# Show that the set of functions with zero integral on $(0,1)$ is a closed subspace of $L^2(0,1)$, with 2-norm

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm self studying functional analysis and have a question.

It is very easy to prove that the set is a subspace of $L^2(0,1)$, from the definition. To prove it is closed, I tried to use the property that a set is closed iff it contains all its limit points. That is, for an arbitrary convergent sequence ${u_{n}}$, each $u_{n}$ satisfies that its integral from $0$ to $1$ is zero. $u_{n}$ converges to $u$, and I want to show that the integral of u is also zero.

But I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1552848/show-that-the-set-of-functions-in-l20-1-with-a-zero-integral-on-0-1-is

Comment: Note that $f(u) = \int f$ satisfies $|f(u)| \le \|u\|$ so it is continuous. Then the set in question is $\ker f$ which is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. It is not that hard. Let $(u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq L^2(0, 1)$ be a sequence with
$$
\int^1_0 u_n~\mathrm{d}x = 0
$$
for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Let $u\in L^2(0, 1)$ be a limit of $u_n$. Then use triangle and Hölder inequality:
$$
\left \lvert \int^1_0 u_n  ~\mathrm{d}x - \int^1_0 u   ~\mathrm{d}x \right \rvert \leq \int^1_0 \lvert u_n-u\rvert~\mathrm{d}x = \lVert 1(u_n - u) \rVert_{L^1(0, 1)} \leq \lVert u_n-u \rVert_{L^2(0, 1)} \lVert 1 \rVert_{L^2(0, 1)} \overset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$
So
$$
0 = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1u_n~\mathrm{d}x = \int^1_0 u ~\mathrm{d}x
$$

This means that $u$ also lies in your subspace. It is thus closed.

Comment: So you've used the Holder inequality, right?

Comment: Yes, I did, when I estimated the $L^1$ norm

Comment: What if we consider $L^2(0,1)$ as Hilbert space with inner product? Can I say the the 2-norm can be induced by the inner product, and the follow all previous steps to show the set converges?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it. You can always do this in Hilbert spaces